# Strange div nesting issue

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am having a strange issue with the website I am working on. For some reason, divs are nesting inside of other divs. This messes up my formatting and it driving me nuts. The problem page is here: http://www.thecadencegrp.com/our-books/page/2

If you scroll down to the bottom of the page, you can see the footer is messed up. I cannot seem to fix it!

Here is the code:

```
 <?php
/*
Template Name: Template Page
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>


<style>

.middler_title{
    width:1000px;
    margin:20px auto 0 auto;
}

#titles-wrapper
{
margin-left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: 80px;
}

#footer { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; display: block; clear: both;}

.middler_title_row {
    float:left;
    width:780px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.middler_title_row img{
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding:0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.middler_title_row h1{
    font-size:30px;
}

.middler_title_row h2{
    font-size:16px;
    margin-top:-38px;
}


.middler_title_row h3{
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top:0px;
}

.middler_title_row h4{
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
}

.middler_title_row a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#005ECF;
}

h3.author-name
{
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#book-navigation
{
width: 240px;
margin: 20px auto;
}

#book-nav-right
{
float: right;
width: 120px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
padding:0;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: left;
}

#book-nav-left
{
float: left;
width: 120px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
padding:0;
font-size: 20px;
}


</style>
<?php 

global $more;

$more=0;
?>

<div id="main-wrap"> <!-- ######################################## -->
<div id="titles-wrapper"> <!-- ######################################## -->

<div class="middler_title">

            <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array(
                'cat' => 1,
                'paged' => $paged
            );
            query_posts($args);

            query_posts('post_type=books&order=DESC&posts_per_page=10&paged='.$paged);
                             while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>               








    <div class="middler_title_row">

                <?php $bookcover = get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'bookcover'); ?>

                         <?php echo $bookcover; ?>

                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                 <?php
            $meta_values = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'subtitle', true);
            ?>  
             <h4><?php echo $meta_values; ?></h4>

            <?php
            $meta_values2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'author', true);
            ?>   
                    <h3 class="author-name"><?php echo $meta_values2 ; ?></h3>


                            <?php
            $meta_values11 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'what_cadence_has_done_to_help_this_book', true);
            ?>


                    <?php
            $meta_values3 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'overview', true);
            ?>

            <?php
            $meta_values4 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'read-more', true);

            if(!$meta_values4){
            $strtitle = get_the_title();
            $title=explode(' ',$strtitle);
            $title=implode('-',$title);
                if(count($title)<1){
                        $title=strtolower($strtitle);
                    }else{
                        $title=strtolower($title);
                }
            $meta_values4 = get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/Books/'.$title;
            }
            ?>   

            <p><?php echo $meta_values11 ?></p>

            <p><?php echo substr($meta_values3,0,340); ?><a href="<?php echo $meta_values4;?>"> ...READ MORE</a></p>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>


    <div id="book-navigation">
       <div id="book-nav-right"><?php next_posts_link('NEXT &#62;&#62;', $the_query->max_num_pages) ?></div>
       <div id="book-nav-left"><?php previous_posts_link('&#60;&#60; PREVIOUS') ?></div>
    </div>


   </div>


</div> <!-- ######################################## -->
</div> <!-- ######################################## -->

  <div id="footer">

    <?php get_footer(); ?>     

  </div>
```

Comment: put </div> before footer starts

Answer (score 0):

if you watch the source of the html in the page you wrote, you will see that there is a 
after you 
also each middler_title_row you print has a

that is not even open.

just open the page in firefox and press Ctrl+U to see the source and you will see a red line of

, this is one of your problems

the other problem is the  coming after the

you need to straight up you html to be valid first before you try to solve this in the css

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 divs with the id = footer. I'd say your problem isn't a mysterious div bug or the css. I'd say your mark up needs some review first of all. Try looking into selectors being ok, and then that every div is closed properly. After that, take a look at the footer. If you want the footer to be stuck in place at the bottom of the place, take a look at something called "Sticky footer". You can accomplish this with some css tricks.

```
<div id="footer">

    <div class="clear"></div>



<div id="footer">

    <div class="thirdpage">
    <br>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/thecadencegroup">
    <img src="http://www.thecadencegrp.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/fb1-300x82.png" width="90">
    </a>
    <br>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/thecadencegrp">
    <img src="http://www.thecadencegrp.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/tw1-300x65.png" width="113">
    </a>
    <br><br>
    <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US </script> <span class="IN-widget" style="line-height: 1; vertical-align: baseline; display: inline-block;"><span style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; text-indent: 0px !important; display: inline-block !important; vertical-align: baseline !important; font-size: 1px !important;"><iframe name="easyXDM_IN_Lib_li_gen_1384155259314_0_provider" id="easyXDM_IN_Lib_li_gen_1384155259314_0_provider" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/js/xdrpc.html?v=0.0.1196-RC1.31125-1408#xdm_e=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thecadencegrp.com&amp;xdm_c=li_gen_1384155259314_0&amp;xdm_p=1#target=li_gen_1384155259314_0&amp;width=600&amp;height=400&amp;mode=wrapper" frameborder="0" style="width: 106px; height: 20px; display: inline-block;"></iframe></span></span><script type="IN/FollowCompany+init" data-id="3323727" data-counter="right"></script> 
    <br><br>
    <h5>© The Cadence Group. All Rights Reserved.</h5>
        </div>


     <div class="thirdpage">

     </div>


     <div class="thirdpage">
      <p>The Cadence Group<br>
      212 Marengo Avenue<br>
      Suite 2S<br>
      Forest Park, IL  60130<br>
      708.689.0908<br>
      <a href="mailto:services@thecadencegrp.com">services@thecadencegrp.com</a>
     </p></div>

</div><!-- /#footer -->

</div>
```

Comment: the problem is with `#titles-wrapper` you can see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your HTML have a problem, but you can remove `margin-left` form `#titles-wrapper` and set `margin-left` to `.middler_title`

here is **CSS**:

```
#titles-wrapper {
margin-left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: 0;   /* removed  */
}

.middler_title {
width: 1000px;
margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
margin-left: 80px;  /* added  */
}
```

the footer section is in the `#titles-wrapper` so when you set margin to `#titles-wrapper` it will move footer to the right. there is another ways but  this is the simplest.

[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BV3Er.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

your footer div is located in titles-wrapper div by this style:

```
#titles-wrapper
{
margin-left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: 80px;
}
```

you can put out footer from this or set margin-left: 0px; in #titles-wrapper style.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

if all the divs are set and tidy, so the `</div>` that i marked cause all the problems, just find it and eliminate it! :D 
usually after the `</html>` you shouldn't have any other tag

the other things that you have to check is why your footer is in `titles-wrapper`, it shouldn't be , because as you can see in the picture `</div> <!--/wrapper-->` is parent of your footer, so consequently your footer will move ahead like `titles-wrapper`, just bring your footer out of your titles-wrapper and everything should be okey